# Eclipse IDE menu windows cut off buttons

Tags: eclipse, menu, ide

I recently installed Eclipse IDE for Java Neon.1 Release (4.6.1) on my Arch Linux 4.8.6-1.

I have the following problem: When I open within the menu a new window the "Back", "Next", "Finish" and "Cancel" buttons are not visible. They are out of the window view.

For example when I want to create a new project. The bottom and the right side is cut off.

[image: new project example]

Even when I resize the window the buttons are still not visible.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?
I have no idea where to start. I searched on google and on this pages but I havn't found someone having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Eclipse Nova does not work properly with the latest GTK launcher.

Go to the {ECLIPSE_HOME|STS_HOME}/*.ini file and replace

```
--launcher.defaultAction
```

with

> --launcher.GTK_version
>   2

This worked for me on Fedora 25.

Comment: Thanks! Now, where you told me the source of the problem, I found it on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/eclipse#Disable_GTK.2B_3) as well.

Comment: In Arch Linux the ini file should be here: /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini

Comment: Thanks a ton. This solution even works on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Eclipse neon.